# Execute two functions with onPressed with conditions

Tags: flutter, dart, button

What I want is to combine those two expressions:

`onPressed: state.isLoading ? null: () => _submit()`
and
`onPressed: !enabled ? null: () => _submit()`

So the button should get disabled, if state.isLoading is true and if !enabled is true. If I use one of the above expression lonely, everything works perfect, but I need to combine them.
My onPressed is defined like this: `final VoidCallback? onPressed;`

I tried the following, but the first condition (if !enabled then null -> disable the button if the textfields are empty) doesn't work.

```
onPressed: () {
  if(!enabled) {
     null;
  } else if (state.isLoading) {
     null;
  } else {
     _submit();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
onPressed: (state.isLoading || !enabled) ? null: () => _submit()
```